# Convert String (with comma) into integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert a string into an integer. The value of the array is 19,99 as a string in my DB column (because of the comma).

```
<% @sales.each do |sale| %>
  <% if current_user.id == sale.user_id %>
   <% price = Warehouse.where(:product => sale.product).pluck(:mrr) %>
   <% price = price.shift.strip.to_i %>
   <% agent = current_user.sales.count.to_i %>
   <%= value = agent * price %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`current_user.sales.count` is `2` and `mrr` is "19,99". I want to multiply those two values but the result is just "38 38".

Does anybody now what to do?

Comment: Why use string instead of float?

Comment: That does only work with a ".", like 19.99. But it's a good start!

Comment: I want to multiply two values of an array (both string/text) and the result should be a float/integer. Turns out that ".to_f" is the right way, but it only allows "." instead of "," (we separate money-values with commas in Germany).

Comment: @Harakiri storing money values as localized strings in a database is a terrible idea. You should use an appropriate numeric data type (e.g. DECIMAL in MySQL) and handle the formatting in your view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 '38,38'.split(',').join('.').to_f * 2
 #=> 76.76
```

Another option is using [String#`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) (thanks @Stefan!):

```
'38,38'.sub(',', '.').to_f * 2
#=> 76.76
```

Comment: That's it thank you! Do you know why it puts two times "39.98" as a result to  <%= value = agent*price.split(',').join('.').to_f %>

Comment: I got it, it's because of the loop.

Comment: do you know how my construct would work without the loop? When I remove the loop I get an "undefined local variable or method `sale' for #<#<Class:0x007fc4a46129f0>:0x007fc49cd55da0>". Sorry I'm very new to rails. :(

Comment: Creating an intermediate array seems a bit complicated. Why not use `str.tr(',', '.')` or `str.sub(',', '.')`?

Comment: @Stefan edited the answer, you are right! Thx for comment!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.to_f` instead of `.to_i` to convert it to float. I should work with comma, too.

http://goo.gl/LZmxW4

Comment: It only converts the integer part into float: `'38,38'.to_f => 38.0`